# Handle client disconnecting/closing the socket

Tags: java, json, sockets, google-chrome-app

I am writing a Chrome packaged application and using the `chrome.sockets` API. The backend is written in Java.

When I close the socket in my Chrome app and check the status, it says it has disconnected as far as my packaged app is concerned.

```
chrome.socket.disconnect(this.getSocketId());
chrome.socket.destroy(this.getSocketId());
```

However my Java backend doesn't throw an error and is blocked on reading. I am reading via the `Gson` library which I think is part of the problem. For whatever reason it is not able to deal with the socket closing in this instance. I find this a bit odd as my test Java client works fine and is able to disconnect fine.

If I read via `InputStreamReader.read()` the result would be `-1` which according to the documentation indicates the end of the stream (I assume that means it knows for sure that the socket is closed).

> JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new
>   InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))
>
> // it blocks at this call
>
> JsonMessage message = gson.fromJson(reader,JsonMessage.class);

How do I handle this disconnection in my Java application and still be able to read the JSON messages?

Comment: Is there only ever one JSON to decode over said socket? If yes you could read the socket contents into a byte[] and process that using a `ByteArrayInputStream` later. You could then handle socket disconnection separately.

Comment: @fge - I am trying to avoid reading into a separate buffer if possible.

Comment: Are you *sending* UTF-8 from the Javascript side? You could be blocked in a character-decoding step inside `InputStreamReader`. Otherwise it looks like you are up against a pretty basic bug in the JSON library you're using.

Comment: @EJP yep, sending an receiving UTF-8 only....I can happily send and receive messages. What do you think is specific to the Chrome app that would cause this to happen?

Comment: Chrome apps use the same stack for XHR than web pages. If you get the expected -1 when reading directly from the InputStreamReader, I think this is a bug in the gson lib. Can you debug and see where it gets stuck after the Chrome app connection is closed?